# How do I send aws ec2 spot instances usage and pricing to s3 bucket using spot instance data feed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am running some spot instances in my AWS account. Now I would like to subscribe to the spot instance data feed. how do I send the ec2 instance usage and pricing to the s3 bucket for every one hour?

```
aws ec2 create-spot-datafeed-subscription --bucket myawsbucket [--prefix myprefix]
```

How to create a prefix in the above command.

Please provide some examples to send the ec2 data to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CLI you could run something like
`aws ec2 create-spot-datafeed-subscription --bucket <s3-bucket-name> --prefix myspotdata`

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-spot-datafeed-subscription.html

if you are using Terraform to manage your AWS resources then below code could be helpful to create Spot feed subscription with prefix

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "spotfeedbucket" {
  bucket = "my-spot-feed-bucket-name"
  acl    = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }
}

resource "aws_spot_datafeed_subscription" "my-spot-feed-bucket-subscription" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.spotfeedbucket.bucket}"
  prefix = "my-aws-spot-datafeed-prefix"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using AWS CLI. can we give any name to prefix tag

Comment: Yes, you can use any `string` for  `--prefix` parameter.
In the above CLI example, I have used `myspotdata` as the prefix.
feel free to accept an answer if you are happy as it may help others.

Comment: @chinna - feel free to accept this as answer if it answers your question as it can help others.